Seasonal adjustment of Brent crude oil price
I need to use the global price of Brent Crude oil (monthly data; Jan-1990, April-2024)
The data set is seasonally unadjusted. I decomposed the trend, and seasonality as it's seen in the following plot.
Do I need to do the seasonally adjustment? If yes, how can I deal with this seasonal adjustment in R?
Thank you.


Whether you need to decompose depends on what you plan on doing. But note that there is very little seasonal signal there, if at all. Take a look at this thread.

With such irregular noise the seasonality that you observe can be overfitting. You see this in the noise before 2000 which has regular yearly peaks. Possibly your seasonality is just capturing a few years, like the peak in 2008/2009 season. By extrapolating that single season with a heavy peak, the noise elsewhere (like pre-2000) is opposite to your seasonality effect.
